# split data using comma, Key containing colon

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split data using comma in key-value pair but value can contain comma:

```
String test2= abc=def,jkl,nm=ghi
String[] testVals=test2.split("(?=,\\w+=)(,)");
```

Now the issue is with below data:

Input:

> ```
> 1,abc=def123,nm=ghi-ghy,jkl,egrh=878787,kjasd:1:1=908@0982
> ```

and i am getting output as:

> ```
> abc=def123
> nm=ghi-ghy,jkl
> egrh=878787,kjasd:1:1=908@0982
> ```

Expected output:

> ```
> 1
> abc=def123
> nm=ghi-ghy,jkl
> egrh=878787
> kjasd:1:1=908@0982
> ```

Here **1** is missing.

Comment: Since 1 is not key value pair.

Comment: actually, the regex you gave should give `1` after a split also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex instead:

```
,(?=[^,]*?=)
```

```
 String test2 = "1,abc=def123,nm=ghi-ghy,jkl,egrh=878787,kjasd:1:1=908@0982";
 testVals=test2.split(",(?=[^,]*?=)");
```

Explanation

- `,` matches comma
- `(?=[^,]*?=)` a positive look ahead asserts that there is no comma between the current matched comma and the next equal sign `=`

**output**

```
1
abc=def123
nm=ghi-ghy,jkl
egrh=878787
kjasd:1:1=908@0982
```

[demo regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/6Utkmy/1)